# How to fetch a particular value from a text file in powershell using regex?

Tags: powershell

```
Linux 4.4.0-38-generic (ajaylinux)  09/27/2016  _x86_64_    (2 CPU)

07:22:03 PM  CPU    %usr   %nice    %sys %iowait    %irq   %soft  %steal  %guest  %gnice   %idle
07:22:03 PM  all    0.16    0.04    0.09    0.16    0.00    0.01    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.55
```

This is my text file and can anyone help me. I need to take values using above headers like %idle 99.55 in powershell. Any help guys

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We are a community to help programmers and programming enthusiasts. That being said, it is expect that you show what you have done or tried before posting. This gives us something to build on. As of now this reads like a code writing request which is off topic for SO. Break your question into its parts and search individually for solutions to those problems. Then, if you are still having issues, please [edit] your question showing your work so we can better help you and the community.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use regex. The file looks like it contains structured data. Read it [as CSV](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849891.aspx) and specify tab char as field separator. Selecting the desired column contents from CSV data is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Use regex to make the log CSV-compatible by replacing two or more spaces to `,`:

```
$data = (Get-Content 'file.txt') -replace '\s{2,}', ',' | Select -skip 2 | ConvertFrom-Csv
```

Since `%` is not a valid identifier character enclose properties in quotes: `$data.'%usr'`
Or strip the character before conversion:

```
$data = (Get-Content 'file.txt') -replace '\s{2,}', ',' -replace '%', '' |Select -skip 2 | 
        ConvertFrom-Csv
$data.usr
```

Comment: thanks for your help but its not working. The scenario is through invoke ssh command am fetching the cpu information from Linux machine and out file it. From that file I want to make use of only particular column like  idle,usr etc etc.

Comment: how to get particular value ... any help pls

Comment: I'm not psychic so I can't know what happens in your code. Use PowerShell ISE to inspect and debug the code.